# matlab isosurface error: V must be a 3D array

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

I am trying to use isosurface to plot a surface described by an implicit function:

```
dvdt0=@(v_i,s_i,w_i)0.1*(-65-v_i)+9*n_i_inf(v_i).^4.*(-90-v_i)...
               +35*m_i_inf(v_i).^3.*h_i_inf(v_i).*(55-v_i)...
               +(s_i).*(v_rev_i-v_i) ...
               +g_M*(w_i.*(-90-v_i));
[v,s,w]=meshgrid(-80:0.1:50,0:0.01:1,1:0.01:1);

val=dvdt0(v,s,w);

fv=isosurface(v,s,w,val,0);
```

However, I keep getting the error message:

```
Error using isosurface (line 73)
V must be a 3D array.

Error in layer (line 9)
fv=isosurface(v,s,w,val,0);
```

Since "val" is obtained from evaluating the function at the meshgrid, and I doubled checked that "val" is the same size as v,s,w, I'm not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following line:

```
[v,s,w]=meshgrid(-80:0.1:50,0:0.01:1,1:0.01:1);
```

The last argument is 1:0.01:1 which is equal to 1.
Change it to

```
1:0.01:2
```

for example.